# Stringstream not showing an output

Tags: c++

I am trying to print some text from a file line by line. The text in the file is:

> 1999 Ford Ranger 3000 156000 used
>
> 2000 Mazda Miata 4000 98000 used
>
> 2015 Jeep Wrangler 33000 250 new

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin; // 'f'ile in - fin       
    std::string filename = "cars.txt";
    bool isOpen = GetInputFileStream(&fin, filename); std::cout << filename << " open: ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isOpen << std::endl; 
    PrintNew(fin, std::cout);
    std::stringstream ssout;
    PrintNew(fin, ssout);
    PrintLine(std::cout, "SS: " + ssout.str());
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

PrintLine function:

```
void PrintLine(std::ostream & sout, std::string s)
{
    sout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The getinputfilestream function opens the specified file and the printnew function which has the following code:

PrintNew function

```
void PrintNew(std::istream & fin, std::ostream & fout)
{
    int modelYear, Price, Mileage;
    std::string Make, Model, Condition;

    while (fin >> modelYear >> Make >> Model >> Price >> Mileage >> Condition) {

        if (Condition == "new")
        {
            fout << modelYear << " " << Make << " " << Model << " " << Price << " " << Mileage << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints the car which is listed as new. Then the stringstream is converted into a std::string but in this case only the output from the printnew function shows up and the text which is supposed to appear after SS: never does. I tried to use fin.clear() at various positions but to no avail, is there something I'm missing?

My output:

```
opening file cars.txt
cars.txt open: true
2015 Jeep Wrangler 33000 250
SS:
Press ENTER to continue
```

Correct output:

```
opening file cars.txt
cars.txt open: true
2015 Jeep Wrangler 33000 250
SS: 2015 Jeep Wrangler 33000 250
Press ENTER to continue
```

Comment: You never gave `ssout` a value, so it's empty.

Comment: What did you observe, while stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I did go through the debugger and saw that after the first call of the printnew function, nothing happens. I have tried the fin.clear() method but still nothing.

Comment: @SarahHyland So, did you step into `PrintNew` function? Stepped through it? Did you observe the values of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you don't have anything in `ssout` is that the contents of the file have been already read when you execute

```
 PrintNew(fin, std::cout);
```

after that, there is nothing to be read from `fin`.

You can use the one of the following methods to be able to read the contents of the file again.

1. Close `fin` and reopen the file.
2. Clear the error states of `fin` and set its position to the start of the file using:

   ```
   fin.clear();
   fin.seekg(0);
   ```

Comment: I have tried fin.clear(); in all the given functions with fin as an argument but it still doesn't show the output.

Comment: @SarahHyland [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) does not reset the file to the beginning of the file (you are missing half of option #2).

Comment: Got it, used seekg to go to 0 and it worked. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @SarahHyland, glad I was able to help. Happy programming.